# ASP.NET meta:resourcekey

Tags: asp.net, localization

I want to use two meta:resourcekey in single control is it possible?

for example
"< asp:LinkButton meta:resourcekey="ImageUrlKey1" meta:resourcekey="ToolTipKey1" >"

Thanks,
Piyush

Comment: A resource key attribute can only be specified once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you have two possibilities:

---

When using implicit localization you define several key/value pairs for the localized properties of the `LinkButton1` in your resource file, e.g. for:

```
LinkButton1.ImageUrl
LinkButton1.ToolTip
```

and then use only one `meta:resourcekey` attribute:

```
<asp:LinkButton meta:resourcekey="LinkButton1" ... />
```

---

Or you use explicit localization instead, i.e. which uses a different syntax instead of `meta:resourcekey`:

```
<asp:LinkButton
  ImageUrl="<%$ Resources:WebResources, Button1ImageUrl %>"
  ToolTip="<%$ Resources:WebResources, Button1ToolTip %>" />
```

---

In any case, have a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx), which explains it in detail.

Comment: Using Resources:WebResources isn't really a change of syntax though is it. Although I agree that going down the global resource file route is an alternative.

Comment: @Joe R: yes, it's probably not correctly worded. But I guess the difference is clear from the examples: with the first approach you specify just one resource key, while with the second approach you have to specify the resource key for each localized property.

Comment: Fair enough. At least you've highlighted an alternative.

Comment: Both the methods are useful for me, the first one is for using Local resource file where my the values are related to page. Some of the part I want to use from Global in which case the second method will be useful.. 
Thanks Martin!!